# java web server and js client - cors problems

Tags: javascript, java

I build a web server in java (simple one) and a client in js 
but when i try to send req its not get the json data the over in the body
may someone know what the problem?

I tried mode: cors / no cors,
I assume that problem is cors problem,
if I set mode: no-cors its work one way (no getting response)
and mode cors not work at all

The java server and it's handler:

```
public class server implements Runnable {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable  = new server();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpServer server = null;
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(3000), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        server.createContext("/getMaze/prim", new PrimHandler());
        server.createContext("/getMaze/kruskal", new PrimHandler());
        server.createContext("/solveMaze/AStar", new AStarHandler());
        server.createContext("/solveMaze/DFS", new DfsHandler());
        server.createContext("/solveMaze/BFS", new BfsHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();

    }


}
```

```
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        // parse request
        he.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        he.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
        he.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT, POST, GET,PATCH, DELETE");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(he.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String query = br.readLine();
        String response = jsonQuery(query);
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
```

here is the js client request

```
await fetch('http://localhost:3000/'+url, {
        mode:'cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"PUT, POST, GET,PATCH, DELETE",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.json);
        return response;
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log(jsonResponse);
        }).catch (error => {
        console.log(error)
        });
```

Comment: You might want to read some things about CORS. With CORS, you usually have an OPTIONS request (a preflight) which checks with your webserver, if the domain, the request is coming from, is allowed. The server sends a header with the allowed host URL. If you want to write this by your own, you need to add some logic.

Comment: It's usually easier to omit CORS and let both the front-end and the back-end run on the same host/port. Locally  for development purposes, you can use a node server with a middleware proxy to the local back-end. You could also just serve your static front-end files with your Java back-end. You might also want to use some framework for the Java web server, so that you don't need to implement it all by yourself.